# How do you lowercase environment variables in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, environment-variables

Is it possible to lower case environment variables from Visual C++ project settings e.g. `$(TargetName)`, `$(ConfigurationName)` etc without having to specify these as new environment variables.  I would like to keep everything lower case to match my unix builds.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible!

Just use `$(MacroName.toLower())`
or `$(MacroName.toUpper())`.

For example:

`$(Configuration)` == `Debug`

`$(Configuration.toLower())` == `debug`

`$(Configuration.toUpper())` == `DEBUG`

---

This works as of Visual Studio 2017, can't tell if it does for older versions, though.

Comment: Can’t remember what I did with this in the end! Will test your suggestion when I get a chance!

Comment: @GrantRogers yep, please do :)

Comment: This worked for me... is there some documentation somewhere about this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it says:

> These macros are not case sensitive.

According to some, $(Target..) is lower case, whereas $(OutputDir) is not necessarely:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/f83e967c-ae19-4073-a9a3-75f2e4482c74
- [Visual Studio 2005 creates output directories in lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359699/visual-studio-2005-creates-output-directories-in-lowercase)

However, I don't know about any documentation confirming this.

Comment: I am using them as part of the output binary name; they come out with the case preserved which is not what I want, I want them all lowercase.  I was hoping there was a function I could run against them to lowercase them or an option.

Comment: I am having the opposite problem to this.  Maybe I should be looking in to the equivalent makefile for Visual Studio and see if there are functions I can run in there.  Will post up when I look in to this.