# Visual Studio Qt Build Error: "This application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized. Available platform plugins are..."

Tags: visual-studio, qt

Hi I have a peculiar situation building my Qt program in Visual Studio 2019 using Qt 5.15.2. This is very similar, somewhat more deeply involved, than [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495620/qt-5-1-1-application-failed-to-start-because-platform-plugin-windows-is-missi). When building in Debug mode the program runs perfectly fine.

When running in release mode, originally I got the error: **The application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.**

After trying the things listed below I get the error: **This application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Available platform plugins are direct2d (from C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms), minimal (from C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms), offscreen (from C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms), windows (from C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms), direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.**

Things I have tried:

1. Setting QT_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable to
   C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\plugins
2. Setting QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH
   environment variable to C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms
3. Setting QTDIR environment variable to C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin
4. Addding C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin to the PATH environment variable
5. Copying libEGL.dll and libEGLvs2.dll to the program's directory
6. Running windeployqt targeting the release executable (this fixed things but I'm interested in fixing
   the problem in a more automated way, I shouldn't have to do this
   every time I build a program or change dependencies)

Anybody know how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get to the properties of the project->build events->post build events in release configuration and type this in the command line: `$(QTDIR)\bin\windeployqt.exe" "$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`

Using this line, whenever I build the solution, all the required files and folders are set in the release folder.

See this topic for more help: [How to integrate Qt's windeployqt as part of Visual Studio build workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788631/how-to-integrate-qts-windeployqt-as-part-of-visual-studio-build-workflow)

Comment: I might have found the solution... give it a try, I think I was trying to do start without debugging in debug mode not release mode. So first change to release mode then go to Debug --> Start Without Debugging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2022